# Filament choice: durable, flexible, long space frame

Tags: filament

I need to build a space frame (see [Structural Mechanics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_mechanics)) which however long it will be (e.g. 2 m), durable, flexible, supporting itself and small weight over. Let's imagine it as a fixed umbrella with that frame under which you can squeeze and come back to shape.

Which filaments should I check?

PS. I know the size is big but it is fine if I build it in pieces.

Comment: You should consider not printing this.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. I do indeed consider that. I have no idea which material even to start from... even if i have to cnc etc

Comment: It should be made from tubes/rods and connectors (do you know the k'nex toy bricks), preferably steel and welded. This is more an Engineering question I guess.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the requirements? I wouldn't go so far as to say you shouldn't print this, but it's possible the best use of 3D printing might be just printing some of the parts from which it can be assembled, or that even if all of it will be printed, that it would benefit from printing as separate parts in their own optimal print orientations which can then be assembled.

Comment: @0scar it is definitely a direction i consider but i was hoping i could go down on weight and fulfill the requirement "squeeze and come back to shape once released".

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE really an umbrella of 2m radius with no moving parts (fixed) is a good parallel. I need to figure out the elements supporting the nylon sheet over. Minimal weight but strong on impacts. That is, it be hit from any direction and does not break but squeezes and returns to shape.

Answer (score 1):

TPU filament is the only thing I can suggest if you must 3d print this gadget. It's strong and flexible.